# Linq 2 Sql DataContext Update Issue During Fetch/Edit/Update Workflow

Tags: linq-to-sql, repository-pattern, asp.net-mvc-3, datacontext

In many of my ASP.Net MVC 3 action methods, I'm having some serious issues with trying to update a record (or set of records) resulting in the following exception:

> An entity can only be attached as
>   modified without original state if it
>   declares a version member or does not
>   have an update check policy.

That's because I retrieve a record via my repository using one DataContext and then, after editing that record, attempt to save it using another new DataContext (i.e. two separate methods in my repository).

The problem is described better than I can ever do in this AzamSharp blog post entitled Dealing with LINQ to SQL DataContext Issues:

http://geekswithblogs.net/AzamSharp/archive/2008/05/17/122222.aspx

I come across many, many posts here and elsewhere with various suggestions, fixes and workarounds but the fact that this seemingly common workflow is not naturally supported in Linq 2 Sql is driving me nuts.

**My question(s) is this... should I abandon Linq 2 Sql for a better approach that handles this workflow natively?  If so, where should I look (EF, EF Code First, 3rd party)?  If not, how do you handle this and get it to work (detach methods in partial classes, timestamps, etc.)?**

I could write specific methods that handle the query and update in one method call but that would require me to add business logic inside the repository which is a no-no (or so I'm told).  Plus that sounds like stored procedure wrapped in C# syntax.  Sort of makes Linq 2 Sql redundant at that point.

Thanks for suggestions.  And if you need code samples, etc. please take a look at the linked blog post above.  It is much more eloquent than I could ever be at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a DataContext that is created each time you create an instance of a repository and not create a DataContext for every method call like in the example.

Here is an example from the NerdDinners [tutorial](http://aspnetmvcbook.s3.amazonaws.com/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v1.pdf) written by ScottGu on how to use Linq To Sql with ASP.NET MVC. It uses one DataContext per repository. It would create a new repository for each web request.

```
public class DinnerRepository 
{
    private NerdDinnerDataContext db = new NerdDinnerDataContext();

    //    
    // Query Methods
    public IList<Dinner> FindAllDinners() 
    {
        return db.Dinners.ToList();
    }  

    public IList<Dinner> FindUpcomingDinners() 
    {
        return (from dinner in db.Dinners
               where dinner.EventDate > DateTime.Now
               orderby dinner.EventDate
               select dinner).ToList();
    }    

    public Dinner GetDinner(int id) 
    {
        return db.Dinners.SingleOrDefault(d => d.DinnerID == id);
    }

    //
    // Insert/Delete Methods
    public void Add(Dinner dinner) 
    {
        db.Dinners.InsertOnSubmit(dinner);
    }    

    public void Delete(Dinner dinner) 
    {
        db.RSVPs.DeleteAllOnSubmit(dinner.RSVPs);
        db.Dinners.DeleteOnSubmit(dinner);
    }    

    //
    // Persistence 
    public void Save() 
    {
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

In more complicated scenarios you can create a DataContext and attach it to the currently running thread in ASP.NET if you have to share the DataContext across multiple Repositories.

Comment: I have found a performance hit when keeping a single datacontext active as opposed to a new one for each call. I found it by accident when I had left an advanced logging toggle on which update a log table to try and pinpoint an issue I was having. Well after a day, instead of the 300 or so tasks in a batch taking between 0 and 2 seconds each to complete with logging, it was taking upto 35 seconds per task by the end of the day. I narrowed it down to the datacontext which when I disposed and re-newed for each batch, never slowed down again.

Comment: If I go with the "unit of work" shelf life of a DataContext (as recommended by MS and John P. above as a "batch"), how would that work in the "context" of fetching a record, editing (based on some business logic) then updating it?  Currently, I'm using two separate DataContext objects each disposed of as soon as I'm done with it.  [The first DC for retrieving the record and second DC for updating, BTW]

Comment: Rick Strahl has an article on this subject that mentioned a few alternative approaches: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/246222.aspx.  This was written a few years ago which makes me even more concerned that this has been an issue for that long and it still hasn't been addressed.  Or am I just going about this all wrong.  Arg! I wish there was a best practice out there for using L2S in a repository pattern.

Comment: @John Petrak thats an interesting experience when keeping the DataContext alive for a long time. The question is for use with ASP.NET MVC so each DataContext will only be alive for a short time so it shouldnt be an issue in this context.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I believe that L2S does offer a "disconnected" data mode where you can query the context for data but the entities returned are automatically detached from the context. This then enables you to edit and then attach them back to your repository in a new data context. Of course, you'll lose all your change tracking so your update will update all the fields rather than just the ones that have changed.

Having said all that, I have tended in the past to do as Joel suggests i.e. have a context bound to the entire repository.

If you are looking to other frameworks - Entity Frameworks support self-tracking entities and disconnected data contexts so that would work for you; however I think that you should be able to achieve your desired behaviour with L2S.

Comment: Thanks for the input Isaac.  I do want to stick with L2S for now even though I can switch later if necessary.  My repositories are not complicated beasts.  I was just hoping there was something I was missing. Some missing piece to the puzzle that I haven't uncovered yet so that updating using a new DataContext is possible with no extra work involved.